# Nuxt3 not importing component

Tags: vue.js, components, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I follow the basic tutorial in order to start a nuxt3 project:

```sh
cd /myfolder
yarn init -y
yarn add --dev nuxt3
yarn nuxi create nuxt3-app
cd nuxt3-app
yarn install
yarn dev -o
```

Then I delete `app.vue`.

I create the directories:

```
mkdir components pages layouts
```

And the files:

```
touch components/Header.vue
touch pages/index.vue
touch layouts/default.vue
```

```html
// components/Header.vue
<template>
  <div>
    HEADER
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
// pages/index.vue
<template>
  <div>
    INDEX
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
// layouts/default.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

However the `Header` component is not included. If I connect to `http://localhost:3000` I see only the word `INDEX`.

What am I getting wrong?

I've followed the tutorial on the official documentation:

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/components/

```
Nuxt project info:                                                                                                                                                                                       

------------------------------
- Operating System: `Linux`
- Node Version:     `v16.13.1`
- Nuxt Version:     `3.0.0-27459267.f69126e`
- Package Manager:  `yarn@1.22.17`
- Builder:          `vite`
- User Config:      `-`
- Runtime Modules:  `-`
- Build Modules:    `-`
------------------------------
```

Comment: You should include the `Header` component inside of the `index` page and not the layout, because only the `slot` is taken into account.

Comment: How can I add a Header in each page then? Also, if you check the documentation, the Header is included in the layout.

Comment: I think you're mixing Nuxt2 and Nuxt3 a little. The Nuxt3 documentation says you need to use <NuxtLayout> to use the layout. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/3770

Run:

```
npm up c12
```